# Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

All,

I am receiving the error "Application defined or object defined error" for a private sub that I have written. The code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim MyLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellmatch

'Find the last row
MyLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Define our comparison
cellmatch = Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, Range(Cells(i, "C")).Value, 0)

'Compare Raw Data cell to Stock column and find a match
For i = 2 To MyLastRow
    If IsError(cellmatch) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = "Not in Stock"
    Else
        Cells(i, 2) = "-"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I have tried several things I found on the forums such us specifying the worksheet

```
Application.WorksheetFuncion.Match.....
```

I've also tried point to the cell or range such as:

```
Range(.Cells(i,"C"))....
```

or
    .Match(.Cells(i,"A"))...

But I keep getting the same error. All of this is happening on the same sheet and I'm not trying to do anything fancy like copying. I am simply asking if a match is NOT found, then label as such, else, label it with a dash (done like this for clarity). I am sure it's something very simple but I am new to coding in VBA. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You cell match line is not in your loop but uses `i`?

Comment: Also your match function is just comparing one cell to another, but it looks like it's supposed to be checking a column rather than a cell...

Comment: You may not get error if you change your corresponding line to this ~cellmatch = Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3), 0)~. I think @Macro Man has also pointed to the same shortcoming in your coding.

Comment: @MacroMan yes, it is supposed to be checking one cell against a column. It should be asking if the there is a cell in the column that matchs the active cell. If not, then it states so. Otherwise, it will state it as a '-'.

Comment: @micstr Oh Duh! Thanks. Yeah, that should have been in my FOR loop. :P I'll make that correction.

Comment: These suggestions worked! I put the cellmatch into the FOR loop (Should have done that the first time, oops!), changed the if statement a bit and it now works as it should. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires change of this code line.

```
 cellmatch = Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, Range(Cells(i, "C")).Value, 0)
```

**TO**

```
 'Adjust Sheetname as per your requirements instead of "Sheet1"
     cellmatch = Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3), 0)
```

**EDIT**

Main problem is coming in your program because of the following code fragment.

```
Range(Cells(i, "C")).Value
```

If we refer to MSDN Documenation
[Range.Cells Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)

It mentions exammples of correct syntax of usage.
Typical example is

```
Set r = Range("myRange") 
For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count 
    If r.Cells(n, 1) = r.Cells(n + 1, 1) Then 
        MsgBox "Duplicate data in " & r.Cells(n + 1, 1).Address 
    End If 
Next n
```

So it translates to `Range("myRange").Cells(n,1)`
    **and not**

```
Range(Cells(i, "C"))
```

It will give correct results as shown in the snapshot.

[image: Snapshot showing results]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim shtCurrent As Worksheet

'Set the sheet to work on
Set shtCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With shtCurrent
    'Find the last row
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Exit if the last row is 2 or smaller
    If lngLastRow <= 2 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to compare!" & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Compare Raw Data cell to Stock column and find a match
    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        'Only compare if there is something in column A to compare
        If .Cells(lngRow, "A").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            'This is the actual MATCH / FIND
            Set rngFound = .Range("C:C").Find(What:=.Cells(lngRow, "A").Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'Evaluate the result of the FIND = rngFound
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value2 = "Not in Stock"                           'not found
            Else
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value2 = "In stock in row " & rngFound.Row        'found
            End If
        End If
    Next lngRow
End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if you have and problems / questions.